# return value in promises

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I defined a function as follows and output 0 or 1:

```
async userLogin ()
```

I used the following code in render but always returned the object:

```
value = this.userLogin()
      .then(function(value) {
        return value;
      })
```

I'm not going to use setstate on userLogin. Is there another solution?

Comment: what is your 'value' type?

Comment: **"I'm not going to use setstate on userLogin."** Then, what will you do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `userLogin()` function resolves a promise that returns a value, and then following should work:

```
const value = await this.userLogin();
// setState here
```

And here's how `userLogin()` should looks like:

```
async userLogin () {
    return LoginFramework.login().then(value => {
        return value;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do it:

```
 // if it is global
 let value = 0; 

 ..... eliminated for brevity

 this.userLogin()
      .then(result => {
         value = result;
      })
```

or use async/await

```
 async testFunction() {
      let value = await this.userLogin();
 }
```